# ¿Qué palabra puede usarse para una acción que en muchos países es considerada delito pero en aquel en el que se dice no?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Hay acciones que cometen las personas que pueden ser muy malas (por ejemplo, vender drogas) y que en la mayoría de los países son ilegales pero en algunos no.

Si estuvieras en un país en donde esa acción es ilegal podrías llamarlo "delito", pero si hablas en uno en que es legal, no puedes llamarlo así a pesar de que la acción puede seguir siendo muy mala en sí y el hablante quiere hacer énfasis en lo malo de la acción.

Entonces, ¿qué palabra puede usarse para una acción que en muchos países es considerada delito, pero en aquel en el que se dice no?

Comment: no creo que exista palabra para definir tal cosa. es como decir que lo que es malo para ti, pero no es malo para alguien mas, forzosamente debe ser malo o tener una palabra en especifico para indicar la diferencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré esta palabra en [Google](https://www.google.com/search?ei=BrFlXduALJ2z5OUPgZOtyAs&q=crimen%20significado&oq=crimen%20significado&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i71l8.2106.3325..3542...0.2..0.0.0.......0....1..gws-wiz.iFmfYT_0ro4&ved=0ahUKEwjbm9ODj6TkAhWdGbkGHYFJC7kQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) que parece funcionar a la perfección: crimen: Acción muy mala y censurable. "es un crimen la caza indiscriminada de ballenas". que según @blonfu figura en el [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=crimen) como: Acción indebida o reprensible.

Comment: Si copias contenido de una web, cítalo y márcalo como tal, por favor

Answer (score 4):

Si la acción está penada en tu país, claro, se considera *delito*. Pero si no está penada, y en otros sí, la acción cuanto menos se podría considerar ***cuestionable***.

Sí, es un adjetivo y no un sustantivo. Siendo un poco laxos con las definiciones, igual podrías usar ***ilícito*** en su acepción de "no permitido moralmente", aunque estoy dando por supuesto que, al ser una acción penada en otros países, podría ser considerada al menos como inmoral en tu país.

Y digo esto último para que tomes todo esto con mucha cautela, porque podría ser que una acción penada en otro país sea algo completamente normal en el tuyo. Has puesto como ejemplo el contrabando de drogas, cosa que en principio podría tener la oposición mayoritaria de la opinión pública, pero por poner otro ejemplo, la homosexualidad está penada en algunos países, y eso no lo convierte en algo inmoral, cuestionable o ilícito en el mío (tal vez sí a nivel personal de cada uno, que hay gente para todo, pero no a nivel legal).

Aunque esta última parrafada no tiene nada que ver con el lenguaje...

Comment: Encontré esta palabra en Google que parece funcionar a la perfección: crimen: Acción muy mala y censurable. "es un crimen la caza indiscriminada de ballenas". Puede ser una definicion válida de la RAE? O es un invento de Google?

Comment: @Pablo *crimen* está bien, según el DLE: Acción indebida o reprensible. Ponlo como respuesta también aunque sea tu propia pregunta

Answer (score 1):

No creo que haya acciones malas en si mismas, el bien y el mal son algo subjetivo aunque pueda haber cosas que en la mayoría de sociedades se consideren inmorales aunque el ejemplo de vender drogas tampoco me parece el mejor para este caso.

Si hablamos de algo que es moralmente reprobable en una sociedad pero no necesariamente ilegal podríamos usar la palabra **inmoral** o algún sinónimo como *ílicito* (dicho por @Charlie aunque se asocia más a la legalidad que a la moral), **deshonesto**, **indecente**, etc.

> **[inmoral](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LfH5iKx)**
>
> 1. adj. Que se opone a la moral o a las buenas costumbres.

> **[deshonesto, ta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=D53p7Bn)**
>
> 2. adj. No conforme a razón ni a las ideas recibidas por buenas.

> **[indecente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LLtMDEf)**
>
> 1. adj. No [decente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BvprV7G), indecoroso.

Comment: Me gusta "inmoral" dado que se apega a las costumbres locales y no a una etica universal, por lo que lo que es inmoral para lguien, es competamente normal para otros

Answer (score 0):

**poco ético**

> **ético**: 1 Que pertenece o concierne a la **ética**; 2 Que obedece a los principios que definen la buena conducta y la convivencia. **L ética**: Conjunto de principios que determinan la conducta, especialmente la que se considera apropiada o moral. ([wiktionary](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9tica))

Y: sin ética,  falto de ética, contrario a la ética, carente de ética, desprovisto de ética,  indebido, contra la ética, antiética.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren las expresiones "supuesto delito", "así llamado delito", "presunto delito", hasta "titulado delito".

¿Tienes algún ejemplo de tu expresión objetivo en alguna otra lengua?